# Iterate through nested object and return child keys as separate array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to iterate through nested Object and I want to store the all the child keys as separate array and return it as a Object(parent key as key and child keys as value).

```
let a = {
  b: {
     f: {
       g: "hi",
       i: "wow"
      },
      e: "hello"
   },
c: {
   j: "ola"
  },
d: {
   k: ["bonjour","salam"]
  }
}
```

And I am expecting object like this.

```
{
  a:[b,c,d],
  b:[f,e],
  f:[g,i],
  c:[j],
  d:[k]
}
```

I tried and got result to some extent.

```
let res = {};
let keyVal;

var isObject1: any = val => {
if (typeof val === 'object' && val)
res[keyVal] = Object.keys(val);
}
function retrieveObj(obj1) {
for (const key in obj1) {
  const value1: any = obj1[key];
  keyVal = key;
  if (isObject1(value1))      
  retrieveObj(value1)
 }
}
res['a'] = Object.keys(a);
retrieveObj(a);
```

Below is the output which I got.

```
 {
  a: [ 'b', 'c', 'd' ], 
  b: [ 'f', 'e' ], 
  c: [ 'j' ], 
  d: [ 'k' ] 
 }
```

can any one help me to get complete output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wv854N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code

1. your `isObject1` check on whether something is an object or not, is not working correctly, because `typeof [1,2,3] == 'object'` will return `true`. You need an additional check for `!Array.isArray(val)`
2. You are handling only the first level. You need a recursive call for nested objects.
3. Not sure what `compare` is in your context
4. You should not define `keyval` as a global variable. If you need to pass values from one scope to another, use parameters, not global variables.

The following should work

```js
let a = {
  b: {
     f: {
       g: "hi",
       i: "wow"
      },
      e: "hello"
   },
c: {
   j: "ola"
  },
d: {
   k: ["bonjour","salam"]
  }
}

function getAllKeys(p, o, m) {
  if (!o || typeof o !== "object" || Array.isArray(o))
    return m;
  m[p] = Object.keys(o);
  
  for (let k of m[p])
    getAllKeys(k, o[k], m)

  return m;
}

let m = getAllKeys("a", a, {})
console.log(m)
```

How does it work

The function `getAllKeys` accepts as parameters

- `p` the name of the property to look at
- `o` the value of the property to look at
- `m` the result object where all the arrays are merged into

First, if the `o` which is passed in, is not a "real" `object` we just return because we don't need to do anything on arrays or primitive types. As `typeof [...]` and `typeof null` also return `'object'` we need the two additional checks ...

Next we add all keys of the current object `o` to the result object under a key of `p` (ie the name of the object we are currently looking at)

And then we check all keys of `o` recursively. Ie, we pass the key `k` and value `o[k]` togehter with the result object `m` recursively into `getAllKeys`.

The final `return m` is just for convinience, so that we don't need to define the resultobject prior to the first call of `getAllKeys`. Without this `return m` we would need to call this as follows

```
let m = {};
getAllKeys("a", a, m);
```

I don't know what you would expect from an object like the following

```
let a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 3
    }
  },
  e: {
    c: {
      f: 4
    }
  }
}
```

The current approach will only return `c: ['f']`. If you want `c: ['d', 'f']`, you would need the following

```
m[p] = [ ...(m[p] || []), ...Object.keys(o)];
```

Comment: I wonder what happens when there are duplicate keys anywhere in the object tree; maybe `m[p] = [...(m[p] || []), ...Object.keys(o)]` instead of `m[p] = Object.keys(o)` so as not to lose them?  ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment. Just had the same thought and worte the update to my answer while you posted that comment.

Comment: @derpirscher thank you